# What is the correct word for a group of categories, tags, and roles?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I want to create a database table that will hold all categories, tags, and user roles. I see WordPress uses "taxonomy" and "term" for this concept. Are there any other words to name it? If not, then which is better: "term" or "taxonomy"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for *[term or keyword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_term)*. A tag is a type of [*metadata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think I will go for `term`. Quick question is `term-able` / `termable`make a sense for something that can be assigned to a term?